# How to pass the captured image (Surface View) to another fragment without saving the image locally?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a Camera app from the googlesamples now, the app captures image and then save it to the local storage. What I want is convert the image into Bitmap and Pass it to another view(fragment)

```
public class Camera2BasicFragment extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

/**
 * Conversion from screen rotation to JPEG orientation.
 */
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

private static final String TAG = "Camera2BasicFragment";
private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0;
private static final int STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1;
private static final int STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2;
private static final int STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3;
private static final int STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4;
private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;
private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
        = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        openCamera(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        configureTransform(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {
    }

};


private String mCameraId;
private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private Size mPreviewSize;

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

};


private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private ImageReader mImageReader;
private File mFile;


private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
    }

};


private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;

private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
private int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;

private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

private boolean mFlashSupported;

private int mSensorOrientation;

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
                Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                if (afState == null) {
                    captureStillPicture();
                } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                        CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture();
                    } else {
                        runPrecaptureSequence();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null ||
                        aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                        aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                    mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                    mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                    captureStillPicture();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                    @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                    @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
        process(partialResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        process(result);
    }

};


private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}


private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
        int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {

    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    // Collect the supported resolutions that are smaller than the preview Surface
    List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
            if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            } else {
                notBigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
    }

    // Pick the smallest of those big enough. If there is no one big enough, pick the
    // largest of those not big enough.
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[0];
    }
}

public static Camera2BasicFragment newInstance() {
    return new Camera2BasicFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.picture).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();

    // When the screen is turned off and turned back on, the SurfaceTexture is already
    // available, and "onSurfaceTextureAvailable" will not be called. In that case, we can open
    // a camera and start preview from here (otherwise, we wait until the surface is ready in
    // the SurfaceTextureListener).
    if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
    } else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
}

private void requestCameraPermission() {
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length != 1 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.request_permission))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

/**
 * Sets up member variables related to camera.
 *
 * @param width  The width of available size for camera preview
 * @param height The height of available size for camera preview
 */
@SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousNameCombination")
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            if (map == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                    mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

            // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
            // coordinate.
            int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            boolean swappedDimensions = false;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
            }

            Point displaySize = new Point();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
            int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
            int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
            int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
            int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

            if (swappedDimensions) {
                rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
            }

            if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
            }

            if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
            }

            // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
            // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
            // garbage capture data.
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                    maxPreviewHeight, largest);

            // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }

            // Check if the flash is supported.
            Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
            mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

            mCameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
        // device this code runs.
        ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    }
}

/**
 * Opens the camera specified by {@link Camera2BasicFragment#mCameraId}.
 */
private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
    }
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
    configureTransform(width, height);
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }
        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Closes the current {@link CameraDevice}.
 */
private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession.close();
            mCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != mImageReader) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}

/**
 * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
 */
private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}

/**
 * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
 */
private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a new {@link CameraCaptureSession} for camera preview.
 */
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
 * This method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in
 * setUpCameraOutputs and also the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
 *
 * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
 * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
 */
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}


private void takePicture() {
    lockFocus();
}


private void lockFocus() {
    try {
        // This is how to tell the camera to lock focus.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the lock.
        mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void runPrecaptureSequence() {
    try {
        // This is how to tell the camera to trigger.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
        // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the precapture sequence to be set.
        mState = STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void captureStillPicture() {
    try {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }

        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

        // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                unlockFocus();
            }
        };

        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.picture: {
            takePicture();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.info: {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}


private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
    private final Image mImage;

    private final File mFile;

    ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
        mImage = image;
        mFile = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have a ViewFragment where I want to retrieve my captured image but how exactly will I able to achieve this? Any suggestions please

Comment: Why not pass the filename as a string extra argument to the other fragment, and then load the file from disk?

Comment: Convert bitmap to encoded string and pass that string to your fragment, in fragment decode string to bitmap..

Answer (score 1):

You should save it temporarily, If you try to transfer with bundle, you could get transaction too large error.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use `Bitmap`, because it is implements `Parcelable`, so it can be passed through bundle.

> BUT! It is no the solution, because bundle max size some where between
>   512  - 1024kb

So in my opinion, better save photo, because it can take **a lot of RAM** as object, and after you receive link on it in your `Fragment`, just delete.

Comment: Good point.Thank you. Last question, where exactly in the code above shall I call the Fragment after I captured the photo?

Comment: @Critics, looks like after your ImageSaver close output. So your file will be ready to show in next fragment.